# How to index .doc and .pdf files in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, pdf, ms-word

How do I index .doc and .pdf files stored in a database (which uses MS SQL Server) in asp.net (C#)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to read into [Full Text Search](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/sqlfulltextindexing.aspx) and [iFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345119(SQL.90).aspx)- here is the [MSDN docs for IFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691105(VS.85).aspx). It looks like there is even an [IFilter MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ifilter/).

This site looks like it has [a good list of filters you can download](http://www.ifilter.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Lucene.net is another well supported option. It's open source, too.